# Entity framework code first:How to disable delete cascade for property attribute?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

How to disable delete cascade for property attribute ?

is there anything like that ?

```
[ForeingKey("UserId",cascadeDelete:false)]
public User UpdatedBy { get; set; }
```

I do not want to use the model builder.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, this isn't how cascading deletes work. If it's enabled, you delete an entity, and all related entities are then deleted. There's no concept of this happening at a more granular (i.e. attribute) level.

Comment: Model :`[ForeingKey("UserId")]
public User UpdatedBy { get; set; }  `

Migrations : `ForeignKey("dbo.User", t => t.UserId, cascadeDelete: true) ` 

i want :  `ForeignKey("dbo.User", t => t.UserId, cascadeDelete: false) `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that by attribute. Use EF fluent API or remove this *OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention* convention.